# Rotating the axes

Tags: coordinate-systems

Mixed term $xy$ is to be removed from the general equation of second degree $ax^2+2hxy +by^2+2gx+2fy+c=0$,one should rotate the axes through an angle $a$ , then $\tan 2a$ has to be found.

My attempt:

$xy$ term can be zero when $h=0$.

The lines would be real if $a$ and $b$ are of opposite signs.

I tried finding the equation of the two lines but that doesn't seem a correct way to proceed further. Pls help me proceed in a better way...

Thankyou

Comment: @jim: no, you can't cancel the mixed term by translation, you need to rotate.

Comment: Pls tell the way to rotate in this particular question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expand

$$a(x\cos\alpha-y\sin\alpha)^2+2h(x\cos\alpha-y\sin\alpha)(x\sin\alpha+y\cos\alpha)+b(x\sin\alpha+y\cos\alpha)^2$$ and collect the mixed terms, giving

$$-2a\sin\alpha\cos\alpha+2h(\cos^2\alpha-\sin^2\alpha)+2b\sin\alpha\cos\alpha=0$$

or

$$(b-a)\sin2\alpha+2h\cos2\alpha=0.$$